# Move dynamic memory to new array, releasing the old memory and not call destructor

Tags: c++, memory

I am implementing a storage class a bit different than std::vector and I ran into a problem when expanding the storage.
Current code to double the size:

```
//T is template class
//_elements is a T* to current array

T* old = _elements;
_elements = new T[size * 2];
memcpy(_elements, old, size * sizeof(T));
delete[] old;
size *= 2;
```

The problem is that delete[] calls the destructor.
Is there a way to free the old memory without calling destructor?

Comment: Don't call `memcpy` on generic types `T` -- this can break the object invariants, in general. Instead, make a true copy (or move) properly calling constructors, and do call the destructors on the old array. To give a concrete example, consider `struct T { char v[10]; char *p = &v[5]; }` -- after the `memcpy` and the `delete/free/whatever`, the pointer `p` is pointing nowhere.

Comment: Another problem is that `memcpy` won't call (copy) constructors.

Comment: Your problem is not just the destructor, but the fact that if constructors and destructors are involved, any usage of `memcpy()` is automatically a bug.

Comment: Get out of the C-mindset. These could be (likely are) complex objects. As such they need actual *copying*, not memory blasting. `std::copy(old, old+size, _elements);` is one possibility. You could also use move-iterators if you were inclined.

Comment: Calling destructors is not a *problem*, it's a feature.

Comment: *Is there a way to free the old memory without calling destructor?* -- Is there a way to stop my car without using the brakes?

Comment: Don't write C++ as if it is C. It is *not*.

Comment: *I am implementing a storage class a bit different than std::vector* -- Unless you have experience beyond the intermediate stage of C++ (and no, knowing C does not count), then doing things like this will only lead to making many mistakes, as you can see from the comments.

Comment: Concrete illustration how that might horribly fail: `class C { class Nested { C& m_parent; public: Nested(C& parent) : m_parent(parent) { } }; Nested m_child; public C() : m_child(*this) { } };` – what happens to the child's reference to its parent on `memcpy`ing? Gets dangling!

Comment: `YourVector<std::string>` -- That immediately breaks everything that you're doing now.

Comment: You need to rethink how you are storing and moving and freeing objects. Currently, you are doing it (horribly) wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hm... Don't think in that specific case, all pointers `std::string` uses should point to external memory and the short string optimisation should rely on an ordinary internal array – *provided* we could avoid calling the destructors – *and* constructors on `new` as well (i.e. we'd need to fall back to `malloc` and `free`, too or maybe `operator new` and `operator delete`). But there sure are thousands of other examples with pointers/references into its own data structure that *will* fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate memory (de)allocation and constructor/destructor invocation.

`memcpy` won't work for non-trivial types; you should be using [`std::uninitialized_move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_move) instead.

The following code is an example of a container allowing to append only. The relevant member function for resizing the storage is `emplace_back`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <new>

template<class T>
class Container
{
    T* m_data { nullptr };
    size_t m_size{ 0 };
    size_t m_capacity{ 0 };

    /**
     * Allocate uninitialized storage for \p n elements
     * \exception ::std::bad_alloc if the memory could not be allocated
     */
    static T* Alloc(size_t n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        T* result = static_cast<T*>(
#ifdef _MSC_VER
            _aligned_malloc(sizeof(T) * n, alignof(T))
#else
            std::aligned_alloc(alignof(T), sizeof(T) * n)
#endif
                
            );

        if (result == nullptr)
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Destruct \p n elements stored starting at \p data and free the memory.
     */
    static void Destroy(T* data, size_t n) noexcept
    {
        std::destroy(data, data + n);
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        _aligned_free
#else
        std::free
#endif
            (data);
    }
public:
    Container() = default;

    // prevent copy & move for now
    Container(Container&&) = delete;
    Container& operator=(Container&&) = delete;

    ~Container()
    {
        Destroy(m_data, m_size);
    }

    template<class...Args>
    T& emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        if (m_size >= m_capacity)
        {
            // move old data to new storage
            auto newCapacity = std::max<size_t>(16, m_capacity * 2);
            auto newMemory = Alloc(newCapacity);
            std::uninitialized_move(m_data, m_data + m_size, newMemory);
            Destroy(m_data, m_size);
            m_data = newMemory;
            m_capacity = newCapacity;
        }

        // append element
        auto& result = *std::construct_at<T>(m_data + m_size, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
        return result;
    }

    T const* begin() const noexcept
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    T const* end() const noexcept
    {
        return m_data + m_size;
    }

};


int main() {
    Container<std::string> container;
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        container.emplace_back(std::to_string(i));
    }

    for (auto& element : container)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
}
```